# "Unknown unclaimed register" System76 Gazelle, Haswell

Tags: kernel

I recently purchased a Gazelle Professional (Haswell) from System76. This is my first step in transitioning from Mac to Ubuntu and I need some help.

From the very fist start up I had an error message, `Unknown unclaimed register`. I also get a flash across the screen right before the message appears.

System76 has dismissed my problem by saying it isn't hardware. I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, which is what came on my laptop.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If boot continues as normal, this is not something of great concern. It is a [bug in the kernel that has been fixed upstream](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58897). Soon, with an update of your kernel, the error message will be gone. For example, if you try drm-intel-nightly, the error message should be gone.

So just be sure to keep installing those updates, and the message will go away. It is erroneous and misleading, and only results due to the kernel's confusion about certain BIOS options.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've been considering returning the laptop over this due to my lack of understanding. This transition is starting to feel quite overwhelming. So much to learn. For example... When you say drm-intel-nightly, is this what you refer to? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-nightly/ Is it ok for me to download "saucy"? I had assumed I needed "raring". I apologize for the stupid question...

Comment: Not a stupid question by any means. Actually, you probably want to try the latest version of the 3.8 kernel first, before trying the nightly build of the kernel. To do that, download all the files ending in "amd64.deb" and the file ending in "all.deb" from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8.13.6-raring/ to your Downloads folder. Then open a terminal with ctrl+alt+T and run this command: `cd ~/Downloads && sudo dpkg -i *all.deb *amd64.deb`. You will be asked to type your password, which will not appear. When you reboot, the issue should be fixed.

Comment: I have this machine as well. According to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-nightly/2013-08-24-saucy/CHANGES and similar our machine (driver drm/i915) is still getting daily updates. I am downloading the kernel now to try out the new driver.

Comment: New kernel installed and booted "uname -a
Linux MasslessC 3.11.0-994-generic #201308240425 SMP Sat Aug 24 08:26:32 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux". If I still have instability issues I will post here.

Comment: Apparently apt has some issue with dependencies, but everything is workling at least as smoothly as before.

Comment: That's good, there's a chance the issue with apt is a separate one unrelated to this... but glad to hear you got things working.