# "Unknown unclaimed register before writing to 4a000" after scanning for Btrfs filesystem

Tags: 14.04, btrfs

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 12 to 14 version.

I see a message `scanning for Btrfs filesystems` before starting up, and then I see an error

```
Unknown unclaimed register before writing to 4a000
```

How can I fix it? I'm new to Ubuntu :/

Comment: Does the computer hang at this point?  If not, does anything else appear to be wrong?

Comment: @MartinThornton no, after that I've got a normal start up. Nothing special. Ubuntu just shows me this error for 1 second and then starts normally

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to be worried about. The error message is the error.

It should go away when Ubuntu installs system updates.  You can force this to happen by typing `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` in the console. See ["Unknown unclaimed register" System76 Gazelle, Haswell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329976/unknown-unclaimed-register-system76-gazelle-haswell)

Comment: Thank you, @MartinThornton/ Hope it will fix with updates of kernel!